# slurm - submit job array to multiple partitions

Tags: configuration, submit, slurm, hpc, job-scheduling

I'm using slurm with multiple partitions such as dev, dev1, dev2..

Therefore when I need to submit huge job array,
I'm always using "-p dev,dev1,dev2" option with python submitit library.

https://github.com/facebookincubator/submitit/blob/main/docs/examples.md

However, the slurm does not distribute the job array to all partitions. job array is pending in dev partition only. other partitions are idle.

In addition, even though there are no jobs in other partitions, new jobs submitted are not running but pending in other partitions.

```
srun -p dev1 echo "hello world"
srun: job 5037027 queued and waiting for resources. 

# slurm does not distribute the job to empty partition.
```

Is it related to fair share policy? or queue configuration?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674796/14598633   . I have never used distributed training on multiple partitions. Do you have a manual from your organisation?