# Can I submit a job that may be executed in different partitions

Tags: slurm

When using the parameter `-p` you can define the partition for your job.
In my case a job can run in different partitions, so I do want to restrict my job to only a given partition.
If my job can perfectly run in partitions "p1" and "p3", how can I configure the `sbatch` command to allow more than one partition?

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45674796/14598633
The second bullet point looks easiest to me.

Comment: --partition accepts a comma separated list of partitions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `--partition` option accepts a list of partition. So in your case you would write

```
#SBATCH --partition=p1,p3
```

The job will start in the partition that offers the resources the earliest.

Comment: I am getting this error: "sbatch: error: Batch job submission failed: Multiple partition job request not supported when a partition is set in the association"